# Where is the Pipe joint addon in Blender 2.7.3?

Tags: modeling, add-on

Hi i'm searching this option at User preferences - Addons, but i can't find it in the new version, even making a search. Has been deleted form blender 2.7.3? I want to turn it on as in older versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now located under *Extra Objects* in the *Add Mesh* category.
[image]

Once you enable it, you can access the custom primitive types with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *> Pipe Joints*.

EDIT:

On version 2.79 Pipe Joints are on Add>Mesh>Mechanical>Pipe Joints

[image]