# 2.83: how to join cylinders and hollow out the junction

Tags: edges, faces

I want to create sewer pipes where a player can walk inside on a 3D game. Then I'm trying to make them by multiple cylinders like this.

[image]

Now I have two problems. First, I don't know how to cut A's edge.

[image]

The other is how to cut B's side  faces.

[image]

I tried to do that by boolean modifier, but it didn't work. So will anyone tell me how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, I'm checking the link.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27407

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular issue arises in the old boolean solver.  The issue is that these shapes are *exactly* the same size and their points are coplanar.  The solver doesn't correctly eliminate all the faces.

[image]

2.91 introduced an exact solver that can be activated with a button in the modifier box, it is for these situations.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it worked!